# JQUERY/AJAX appending data to the end of a specific row instead of the bottom of the table

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table with some data that I am appending to a row of another table. I have the appending working ok but only to the bottom of the table instead of the row itself. The row is not the last row in the table so I cant use last-child etc. How do I fix that?

AJAX

```
function options(id_In{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: {action: 'options_function',cid : id_In},
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery('table#ideal_option').append(data);
        }
```

**HTML from table:**

```
echo "<table id ='ideal_option'>";  

foreach($check_availability as $available){ 
    $id=$available->id;
    $foh_nmbr=$available->FOH_Number;
    $tl_type=$available->Type;
    $sf_name=$available->Staff_First_Name;
    $sl_name=$available->Staff_Last_Name;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $foh_nmbr . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $tl_type . '</td>';
    echo("<td><select>");
foreach($Staff_On_Duty as $person){         
    $sf_name_option=$person->Staff_First_Name; 
    $sl_name_option=$person->Staff_Last_Name;
    echo("<option value = $sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option");
    if (($sf_name_option == $sf_name) && ($sl_name_option == $sl_name)) echo (" selected");
    echo(">$sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option</option>"); 
}
echo("</select></td>");
    
    echo '<td>' . "<button id='party' class='button ' onclick='party($id, $cid)'><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i></button>" . '</td>'; 
echo '</tr>';}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Can you add the structure of your html table? because I am confuse why there is an ID on your table body :)

Comment: absolutely, just did. The id is there to append to and have a reference. If there is a better way, I am all eyes Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your HTML code example your table don't have a tbody so you can try this one on success

```
jQuery('table tr#specificIDorClassRow').append(data);
```

Comment: thanks sorry that is a typo on my end,. I ahve the append function working ok though. (Using exactly what you have here). How do I bind it to a specific row instead of the end of the table?

Comment: You can add id or class on that specific row then change the append to like this `jQuery('table tr#specificIDorClassRow').append(data);`

Comment: Thanks! And to complicate it even further, what if that row isnt always the same and there are many rows and I want to append data to each row depending on the values passed form the button?

Comment: also if you want to change your answer above to jQuery('table tr#specificIDorClassRow').append(data); then I can accept it since that was technically the question :)

Comment: You can use the id or as an attribute of row the variable `$id` in that way you can track all row and append on each row with unique ID the same with your button